# Can't access elements in the same webpage after clicking with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, nested

I am trying to obtain the addresses of Walmart stores after searching Walmart.com by zip code using Python Selenium.  I have searched here and online but I can't find a solution. The list of stores within the zip code populates, and I can loop through that list to get the name of each store, but then another click on a "Details" button is required to see the full address.  After clicking on "Details" the information appears in the same area as the list of stores, but, I cannot obtain any information within the new "window" that appears after clicking "Details" and the looping stops.  See pictures of the website below.

[image: Walmart Screen 1]

[image: Walmart Screen 2]

I have tried "wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH..." and tried to switch between elements, windows and frames, but none of them work.

Here is some code I tried and you can see other things I tried that are commented out.  While there are no errors, it doesn't work:

```
zip_code = '60639'
w_browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
ws_url = 'https://www.walmart.com/store/finder?location=' + zip_code + '&distance=30'
w_browser.get(ws_url)

w_div = w_browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="store-list"]/div/ol/li//a')

w_tic = str(0)
w_store_names = []
w_add_names = [] #
for ws in w_div:
    w_tic = int(w_tic)
    w_tic = w_tic +1
    w_tic = str(w_tic)

    try:
        w_store = w_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="store-list"]/div/ol/li[' + w_tic + ']/div/div[2]/span[1]/div[1]')
        print(w_tic)
        w_store_names.append(w_store.text)
        print(w_store.text)
        # main_page = w_browser.current_window_handle
        # time.sleep(1)

        # button = w_browser.find_element_by_link_text('store-icon-link-text')
        button = w_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="store-list"]/div/ol/li[' + w_tic + ']/div/div[2]/span[2]/span/span')
        button.click()
        time.sleep(1)
        print('I clicked Details')

        wait = WebDriverWait(w_browser, 5)
        add_menu = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="store-finder-results"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div')))
        ActionChains(w_browser).move_to_element(add_menu).perform()

        # back_button = w_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="store-finder-results"]/div/div/div[1]/button/span/span[1]')
        # back_button.click()
        
        # store_button = find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="store-finder-results"]/div/div/div[1]/a/button/span')

        # action = ActionChains(w_browser)
        # action.click(on_element = store_button)
        # action.perform()
    
        # for handle in w_browser.window_handles:
            # if handle != main_page:
                # add_page = handle
                
        # w_browser.switch_to.window(add_page)

        # w_frame = w_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="store-finder-search-container"]')
        # w_browser.switch_to.frame(w_frame)

        w_ea = []
        w_range = (1, 5)
        for w_er in w_range:
            w_elem = w_browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="store-finder-results"]/div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[' + str(w_er) + ']')
            w_ea.append(w_elem.text)
            print(w_elem)
        w_add_names.append(w_ea)

        # w_browser.switch_to.window(main_page)
        # time.sleep(1)

    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass

print('WALMART STORES:')
print(w_store_names)
w_count = len(w_store_names)
print('There are ' + str(w_count) + ' Walmart Stores in Zip Code ' + str(zip_code))

w_browser.quit()

print(w_add_names)
```

I think that I have to somehow switch to the new (nested?) information pane that shows up after clicking "Details," and the switching back to get to the next store, but I don't know how.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do get all stores for a zip code you don't need to use Selenium and so complicated code. Check [tag:requests] and [tag:beautifulsoup]

Comment: Thanks Sers, I would prefer to use Beautifulsoup but I tried that and it didn't work, maybe I'm just not good with Beautifulsoup.  I need to get that one specific string of text that has the store address.  I don't care whether its Beautifulsoup or Selenium (I only used Selenium because it worked).  I can count how many stores there are just based on the first screen without clicking, but I cannot seem to find how to access that address string in the second screen because I don't know how to tell the machine to retrieve it.  Is Selenium somehow preventing me from getting the address?